# How to pass an array in JSON

Tags: arrays, json

I have to pass json in following fornmat for API testing. How can I achieve it? The array length is dynamic.

```
   {
    key1:"value",
    key2:"value2",
    key3:{
      key4:[{
        key5:"value5",
        key6:[{
          key6:"value6[0]",
          key7:"value7[0]"
          },
          {
          key6:"value6[1]",
          key7:"value7[1]"
          }]
          }]
  }}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case of Java, you can use JSONObject and JSONArray to parse your JSON string or create POJOs for this structure. It will depend on your final goal.